# How to Protect a database from directly deleting by other users than me?

Tags: sql-server, security

I want to protect my database from deletion by anyone.
Like for example if anyone connect to my server and accesses any data from my database it is ok even if they manipulate the data like INSERT,UPDATE but deletion should be only performed by me only and not by anyone else.

Only I should be able to delete the database 
Can anyone help....

Thanks,

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: Sounds like you need a short tutorial on SQL Server security.

Comment: Then don't *grant* them that permission in the first place. The default behaviour for SQL Server is that users cannot do anything. It's only be granting them permissions (or assigning them to roles which have permissions) that they gain the ability to do anything

Comment: Don't forget that you can delete almost as much data through an UPDATE as you can through a DELETE. Think carefully about what your actual requirements are.

Answer (score 1):

You should create server roles and add logins to that role and assign permission and prohibit access to special database deny drop.

Answer (score 0):

You can revoke the drop privileges from the users to whom you don't want to delete the databases. Using the below command:

Example for mysql:

First login as root:

```
mysql -u root -p
```

Then use the below command to revoke drop privileges from a user such that no database deletion is allowed by that user:

```
REVOKE DROP ON *.* FROM 'username'@'SERVER'
```

SERVER is equal to localhost if you have database on your local computer.